# Separate Database relevant properties from Business Logic

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I‘m changing a project with Entity Framework database first approach to code First. 
At the moment there is an additional partial class to each poco which contains additional properties and methods. Some of the partial classes even extend base classes.

As first step I created entity classes for each poco an added an entity configuration.

Now I‘m not sure how to proceed with the partial classes. It would feel wrong to just add all this business logic to the entity classes. Furthermore I would have to add the NotMapped attribute to each of the additional properties and I worry that in the future somebody will add properties and forget to add the NotMapped attribute that can cause trouble with the migrations.

So I‘m wondering how I can separate the entities and the additional properties and methods? What is the best practise for this? Thank you!

Comment: EntityConfiguration

Comment: @joey Can you please concretise your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved this issue:

I created one folder called "Entities" and one folder called "DomainEntities" and put a copy of each entity class into each of the folders. Then I added all the business logic from the partial classes to the DomainEntities. The classes of the Entities folder are only used for the database operations. 
I use automapper to map the entities to the domain entites and vice versa.

If anybody knows a better approach, please share.